# How to create multidimensional array with for loop in javascript like this

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need create multidimensional array in runtime like;

```
var terv=var people = [
  { "name": "bob", "dinner": "pizza" },
  { "name": "john", "dinner": "sushi" },
  { "name": "larry", "dinner": "hummus" }
];
```

sample code is here.

```
for (i = 0; i > Resrot.length; i++)
{
    var Array = [
        { "name": resId[i], "dinner": rotname[i] },
    ];
}
```

how can do it? Any suggestion?

Comment: That isn't a multidimensional array (in js an array of arrays), it is just an array of objects.

Comment: Read up on how to use [Array#push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this is not a multidimensional array, it's an array of objects. You can create it like this.

```
var objectsArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < Resrot.length; i++) {

    objectsArray.push( { "name": resId[i], "dinner": rotname[i] } );

}
```

Comment: I have removed my answer, as it is similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
let multiDimensionalArray = new Array(5);

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  multiDimensionalArray[i] = new Array(2);
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.